# how to get value of a <select> without <form> HTML markup

Tags: php, html

i never put too much thought on how the data would be submitted without using `<form>` . I initially just focused on the design of my form.

now, im having trouble trying to send `POST` data without having a `<form>` markup.
im using `bootstrap` framework.

also, how do i get the values in my `<select>` markup to be submitted. below is my HTML and PHP code.

below HTML

```
<div id="box1">
   <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="name">
</div>

<div id="box2">
   <select id="food" name="food">
       <option value="meat" name="nmeat">   meat  </option>
       <option value="fruit" name="nfruit"> fruit </option>
    </select>
</div>

// ^ Above code is in a JQuery Conditional Statement
// When user select meat, <select id="meat"> will display else fruit


<div id="box3">
   <!--MEAT-->
   <select id="meat" name="topic">
       <option value="hotdog" name="nhotdog">   hotdog     </option>
       <option value="sausage" name="nsausage"> sausage    </option>
    </select>

    <!--FRUIT-->
    <select id="fruit" name="topic">
       <option value="apple" name="napple">   apple   </option>
       <option value="grapes" name="ngrapes"> grapes  </option>
    </select>

 </div>

<div id="box4">
   <textarea name="desc" rows="5" class="span11" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
   <button name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>

</div>
```

below PHP
Im having a hardtime making the correct syntax in PHP, specially if the values being submitted is not in a `<form>`

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $name = $_POST["fname"];   //box1
        $gender =$_POST["gender"]; //box2
        $topic =$_POST["topic"];   //box3
        $desc =$_POST["desc"];     //box4
        //echo $msg;
        $sql = "insert into z_form (name) values ('".$msg."')";
        mysql_query( $sql );
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there any valid reason to not put a `<form>` tag?

Comment: If you were using GET then you could possibly get (no pun intended) away with not using a form. POST requires a form.

Comment: $_POST["<name>"] messages are processed by HTML form... Ofc you can do this without using the form tags, but it's just more complex.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `<form>` tag, really. `POST` method requires a `<form>` tag. I don't see any valid reasons to exclude the `<form` tags from a form.

> now, im having trouble trying to send POST data without having a  markup. im using bootstrap framework.

Bootstrap doesn't restrict you from using `<form>` tags. :)

Wrap your form in `<form` tags, as follows:

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="post" name="myForm">

<!-- your form code here -->

</form>
```

Also, change your button from:

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"/>
```

And finally, in your PHP code, you're doing:

```
$gender =$_POST["gender"];
```

But there's no input field with the name attribute `gender`. Either you should create one input field with that name, or remove the definition from your script.

That should fix the issues. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not use a `<form>` ? all other methods consist of using jquery in combination with ajax, or just ajax for sending the values. But there shouldn't be a reason to not use a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include form tags:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    //form content
</form>
```

Change your submit button. It's also good to change the name to somthing other than "submit" to avoid namespace conflicts:

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" value ="Submit" />
```

Also, give your selects different names (You have two with the name "topic"):

```
<select id="meat" name="meat">
   <option value="hotdog" name="nhotdog">   hotdog     </option>
   <option value="sausage" name="nsausage"> sausage    </option>
</select>
```

And then retrieve those values from `$_POST`:

```
$meat = $_POST['meat'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `#box3` you have 2 selects with the same name.

Try something like:

```
<select id="meat" name="meatSelect">
<select id="fruit" name="fruitSelect">
```

And then:

```
$meatSelect = $_POST['meatSelect'];
$fruitSelect = $_POST['fruitSelect'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that you have to use the -tag if you want to submit data just with submit button.
An alternative is to take a button and use javascript / jquery to read data from fields and submit them via get-parameters with an url.
However it seems you would like to go the classic / easy way. So you need the  and define the method and action.

In addition a little hint: Try to use a php framework with mvc-(model view controller)pattern. When you use it in the right way it makes you easier to handle your code, brings predefined functions / classes and makes your functions against database safer. An example for such a framework would be codeigniter but there are many more...

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $(button).click(function() {
var name=$("#name").val();
 var frt=$("#fruit").val();
var gender = $("#gender").val();
var topic= $("#topic").val();
var descr= $("#description").val();
 var dataString = 'name='+name+'fruit='+ frt+'gender='+gender+'topic='+topic+'desc='+descr;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
 url: "ajax.php",
data: dataString,
  cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#success").html(html);
} 
});

 });
});
</script>
```

You should add id in all dropdown fields.
also add which you want to view the show success or error result

```
<div id="success"></div>
```

Comment: Don't build query strings by hand. jQuery has perfectly good functions which will do that for you *and properly escape that data*.